# How would i use the distance formula to determine the distance between the point (2,1,6) and the yz-plane?

Tags: vectors

How would i use the distance formula to determine the distance between the point (2,1,6) and the yz-plane? 
Can someone provide the final answer and the steps if possible

Comment: you would travel from your point to the plane in a direction perpendicular to the plane.  The point of intersection is the point on the plane closest to your initial point.  Then use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the distance between the two points.

Answer (score 2):

The $yz$ plane has equation $x=0$ so just find the distance from the point $(2,1,6)$ to its nearest point in the $yz$ plane, namely, the point $(0,1,6)$, for which you do not even need the distance formula, but you may use it.

Answer (score 0):

The distance of a point $\vec{r}$ with a plane through the origin with normal vector $\hat{n}$ is simply

$$ d = \vec{r} \cdot \hat{n} $$

<sub>where $\cdot$ is the dot (inner) product</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The distance of the point from the $yz$ plane is simply the absolute value of the $x$ coordinate of the point.

The equation of the plane is simply $x=0$.

Using the point-distance formula from $ax + by + cz + d = 0$ to point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$

$$D = \frac{|ax_0 + by_0 + cz_0 + d|}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}},$$

We see that $b=c=d=0$ and $a=1$ so

$$D = \frac{|1(2) + 0(1) + 0(6) + 0|}{\sqrt{1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2}} = 2.$$

Comment: do you know how to solve this too please

Comment: Give a vector equation and corresponding parametric equation for the following
-the line parallel to the x-axis passing through P(2,4)
-the line parallel to the y-axis, passing through Q(-2,-1)
Does anyone know the answers to these

Comment: @requoied That's a separate question.  Use the "Ask Question" at the top of the page for this.

Comment: it will not allow me, it says it isn't a valid question idk what to do @john

Comment: @requoied Also, I recommend that you show what you've tried when you ask the question.  If you start out with too many questions that get downvotes, you won't be allowed to ask more.

Comment: Are you putting the entire question in the title area?  Make a title to summarize what the question is about, then use the bigger area to ask the question.

Comment: I still wont let me, this is the only question I don't understand how to do at all, can u please help @john

Comment: Take a look at how people type up their questions.  Try to write it as best as you can.  It looks like some algorithm is making the determination that your question is low quality.  But I can't get into the habit of answering extra questions in the comments section.  That's not what this area is for.